# Installation of eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

Problem statement :

> "Error Occuring in log files during installation of eclipse"

Above is error comes up every time when I try to install eclipse in my system "Windows 10"

Please help me with this

Comment: Look in the log file it tells you about for a detailed error message

Comment: what is the error logs says  ?

Comment: "Error Occuring in log files during installation of eclipse " this statement keeps occuring no other specific error